# Optimization: Center of gravity method, what is the $\text{vol } S_1$?

Tags: integration, notation, convex-analysis

This is a notation question. I am learning about some microsoft center of gravity optimization algorithm.

In my example I am trying to find the minimum of $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ where $x\in[0,3]$, by using the center of gravity method. Let $S_1 = \textbf{dom } f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a convex function.

To do this I need to find the first point,

\begin{align}
c_1 = \frac{1}{\text{vol}(S_1)}\int_{x\in S_1} xdx = \frac{\int_{x\in S_1} xdx}{\int_{x\in S_1} dx}.
\end{align}

Then I "query the first order oracle at $c_1$", to obtain $w_1\in \partial f(x)$. Then we can let,
$$
S_2 = S_1 \cap\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: (x-c_1)^Tw_1\leq 0\}.
$$

I took these notations from two sources, the first one is from [a research paper](https://docdro.id/Clrt5sx), the other is from [some slides](https://docdro.id/xSMdgnf). Pretty much I am confused about the integrals.

Do these integrals $\int_{x\in S_1}$ have a specific name?

How do I compute $\int_{x\in S_1} xdx/\int_{x\in S_1}dx$ given only that $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ and $\textbf{dom } f(x) = [0,3]$?

What the hell does $w_1$ do and how do I get it from an oracle?

**My Attempt**

Starting with the volume of $S_1=[0,3]$,
$$
\text{vol }(S_1) = \int_{x\in S_1}dx = \int_0^3dx = 3
$$

Next for the numerator,
$$
\int_{x\in S_1} xdx = \int_0^3 xdx = \left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_0^3 = \frac{9}{2},
$$
Which means $c_1 = \frac{9}{2}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{2}$.

I guess in this case because I know the function, my oracle can just be the derivative of $f(x)$: $f^\prime(x) = 2(x-1)$. This gives us $w_1 = f^\prime(\frac{3}{2}) = 1$.

This part is really hard for me, finding $S_2$, I guess it literally just means the domain to the left of $S_1$ at $w_1$ if $w_1>0$ and the right if $w_1<0$. If $w_1=0$ then we are obviously at the minimum. So in this case maybe $S_2 = [0,\frac{3}{2}]$??? Geeze I think I am getting it, but it just seems so complicated compared to other methods, and I have no idea if this is correct.

Solving for $c_2$ with $S_2=[0,3/2]$ gives me $c_2=\frac{9}{8}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{3}{4}$ on paper. $f^\prime(\frac{3}{4}) = -\frac{1}{2} < 0$ so $S_3 = [\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{2}]$. Cheating I know that $x_min=1\in[\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{2}]$, so yup seems to be working.

I still would appreciate anyone giving me some feedback or context on this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do these integrals $\int_{x\in S_1}$ have a specific name?

Well, that's just "integral over $S_1$", which precisely means: taking the sum over all elements of $S_1$.

> How do I compute $\int_{x\in S_1} xdx/\int_{x\in S_1}dx$ given only
> that $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ and $\textbf{dom } f(x) = [0,3]$?

No answer needed here because you already did this in your question.

> What the hell does $w_1$ do and how do I get it from an oracle?

The intuition behind the center of gravity method is quite simple: if you can find a subgradient ($w_t$) at the center of gravity ($c_t$), then you can find a hyperplane that cuts the domain into two halves and you know exactly which half contains the minium.

Here the oracle means: *Find a subgradient at $c_t$*. If your function is differentiable then this means: *Find the derivative at $c_t$*.

> **My Attempt**
>
> Starting with the volume of $S_1=[0,3]$, $$ \text{vol }(S_1) =
> > \int_{x\in S_1}dx = \int_0^3dx = 3 $$
>
> Next for the numerator, $$ \int_{x\in S_1} xdx = \int_0^3 xdx =
> > \left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_0^3 = \frac{9}{2}, $$ Which means $c_1 =
> > \frac{9}{2}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{2}$.
>
> I guess in this case because I know the function, my oracle can just
> be the derivative of $f(x)$: $f^\prime(x) = 2(x-1)$. This gives us
> $w_1 = f^\prime(\frac{3}{2}) = 1$.

This is correct.

> This part is really hard for me, finding $S_2$, I guess it literally
> just means the domain to the left of $S_1$ at $w_1$ if $w_1>0$ and the
> right if $w_1<0$. If $w_1=0$ then we are obviously at the minimum. So
> in this case maybe $S_2 = [0,\frac{3}{2}]$??? Geeze I think I am
> getting it, but it just seems so complicated compared to other
> methods, and I have no idea if this is correct.

This is just an intersection of two sets. The first set is $\mathcal{S}_1 = [0,3]$, the second is $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (x-3/2)\times 1\leq 0\} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: x \le 3/2\} = (-\infty, 3/2]$ (this is the "half" that must contains the minium when you cut $\mathcal{S}_1$ into two halves). The intersection between $[0,3]$ and $(-\infty, 3/2]$ is obviously $[0,3/2]$. You did it right. What's difficult here?